# How inset a string in list item in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.7

I have list:

```
['Happy Family','2122540624','213 E Broadway # A, New York, NY 10002, United States']
```

I want to add a ',' into first item like this:

```
 ['Happy Family,','2122540624','213 E Broadway # A, New York, NY 10002, United States']
```

Any friend know how to do it?

Comment: Please be aware [so] is not a code-writing service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyList = ['Happy Family','2122540624','213 E Broadway # A, New York, NY 10002, United States']
MyList[0] = MyList[0] +','
```

Result:

```
['Happy Family,', '2122540624', '213 E Broadway # A, New York, NY 10002, United States']
```

You can try it

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the item by index and add a comma as below:

```
a = ['Happy Family','2122540624','213 E Broadway # A, New York, NY 10002, United States']
a[0] = f'{a[0]},' # f-string above python 3.6 otherwise a[0] = a[0] + ','
print(a) # Outputs ['Happy Family,', '2122540624', '213 E Broadway # A, New York, NY 10002, United States']
```

Comment: Or just `a[0]=a[0]+','`

Comment: Yep, but `f-string` is the pythonic way I guess

Comment: *Yep, but f-string is the pythonic way I guess* -- for versions that support f strings. It has only been supported since v 3.6

Comment: I thought the tag said `3.7`. Anyway, I added your suggestion

Comment: I really don't see how an f-string is Pythonic here. "add a comma to the first element" is *literally* ``a[0] += ','``. There is no need to roll out format syntax here, which at worst even obscures what happens when using realistic variable names.